# Value of $_GET Superglobal Not Being Passed To Processing Page

Tags: php, sql

Ultimately I am trying to delete an admin by id. I know the id of the admins are making it to the list admins page because I am printing the admin id in the table next to each admin username and seeing the id.  But when the delete admin link is clicked, the delete admin page is not receiving the id from the GET superglobal.

Why not?
Thanks,
CM

list_admins.php (contains the delete button at the bottom for deleting an admin)

```
<?php require_once("../../includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<?php //if (!$session->is_logged_in()) {redirect_to("login.php");} ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>

<?php
  $admin_set = User::find_all();
  $message = "";
?>

<?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>
<?php include("../layouts/admin_header.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
  <div id="navigation">
        <br />
        <a href="index.php">&laquo; Main menu</a><br />
  </div>
  <div id="page">
    <?php echo output_message($message); ?>
    <h2>Manage Admins</h2>
    <table style="border: 1px solid #000; color:#000;">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Username</th>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">User Id</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    <?php foreach($admin_set as $admin) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $admin->username; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $admin->id; ?></td>
        <td><a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php $admin->id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php $admin->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <?php echo $admin->id?>?');">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
    <br />
    <a href="new_admin.php">Add new admin</a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include("../layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

delete_admin.php

```
<?php require_once("../../includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<?php if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); } ?>

<?php
  //$admin_set = User::find_all();//This works, var_dump shows me the users are 
    //being returned
  //var_dump($admin_set);

  $admin = User::find_by_id($_GET['id']);//This returns database query failed.
  var_dump($admin);
?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
// If it's going to need the database, then it's 
// probably smart to require it before we start.
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');

class User extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $table_name="admins";
    protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name');

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

  public function full_name() {
    if(isset($this->first_name) && isset($this->last_name)) {
      return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

    public static function authenticate($username="", $password="") {
    global $database;
    $username = $database->escape_value($username);
    $password = $database->escape_value($password);

    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM users ";
    $sql .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
    $sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
    }

    // Common Database Methods
    public static function find_all() {
        return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name);
  }

  public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name." WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
      $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }
    return $object_array;
  }

    public static function count_all() {
      global $database;
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".self::$table_name;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
      $row = $database->fetch_array($result_set);
    return array_shift($row);
    }

    private static function instantiate($record) {
        // Could check that $record exists and is an array
    $object = new self;
        // Simple, long-form approach:
        // $object->id              = $record['id'];
        // $object->username    = $record['username'];
        // $object->password    = $record['password'];
        // $object->first_name = $record['first_name'];
        // $object->last_name   = $record['last_name'];

        // More dynamic, short-form approach:
        foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
          if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
          }
        }
        return $object;
    }

    private function has_attribute($attribute) {
      // We don't care about the value, we just want to know if the key exists
      // Will return true or false
      return array_key_exists($attribute, $this->attributes());
    }

    protected function attributes() { 
        // return an array of attribute names and their values
      $attributes = array();
      foreach(self::$db_fields as $field) {
        if(property_exists($this, $field)) {
          $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
        }
      }
      return $attributes;
    }

    protected function sanitized_attributes() {
      global $database;
      $clean_attributes = array();
      // sanitize the values before submitting
      // Note: does not alter the actual value of each attribute
      foreach($this->attributes() as $key => $value){
        $clean_attributes[$key] = $database->escape_value($value);
      }
      return $clean_attributes;
    }

    public function save() {
      // A new record won't have an id yet.
      return isset($this->id) ? $this->update() : $this->create();
    }

    public function create() {
        global $database;
        // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
        // - INSERT INTO table (key, key) VALUES ('value', 'value')
        // - single-quotes around all values
        // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
        $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
      $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
        $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
      $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
        $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
        $sql .= "')";
      if($database->query($sql)) {
        $this->id = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public function update() {
      global $database;
        // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
        // - UPDATE table SET key='value', key='value' WHERE condition
        // - single-quotes around all values
        // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
        $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
        $attribute_pairs = array();
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
          $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
        $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
        $sql .= " WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
      $database->query($sql);
      return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
    }

    public function delete() {
        global $database;
        // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
        // - DELETE FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1
        // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
        // - use LIMIT 1
      $sql = "DELETE FROM ".self::$table_name;
      $sql .= " WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
      $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
      $database->query($sql);
      return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;

        // NB: After deleting, the instance of User still 
        // exists, even though the database entry does not.
        // This can be useful, as in:
        //   echo $user->first_name . " was deleted";
        // but, for example, we can't call $user->update() 
        // after calling $user->delete().
    }

}

?>
```

database.php

```
<?php 
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");

class MySQLDatabase{
    private $connection;

    function __construct(){
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    public function open_connection(){
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          die("Database connections failed: " . 
               mysqli_connect_error() . 
               " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
          );
        }
    }

    public function close_connection(){
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql){
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    private function confirm_query($result_set) {

        if (!$result_set) {
            die("Database query failed yo.");
        }
    }

    public function escape_value($string) {
    $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $string);
    return $escaped_string;
}
//database neutral functions
    public function fetch_array($result_set){
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
    }

    public function num_rows($result_set){
        return mysqli_num_rows($result_set);
    }

    public function insert_id(){
        return mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
    }

    public function affected_rows(){
        return mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection);
    }
}//End class MySQLDatabase
$database = new MySQLDatabase();
?>
```

Comment: That's too much code dumped here. Provide an [MCVE]. Also some access.logs or browser HTTP request debugging, or `print_r($_SERVER);` at least.

Comment: What does it dump with var_dump($admin); ? (just to check if you have null, or some values). In which files are you accessing $_GET apart from delete_admin.php ? Could you give the output of var_dump($_REQUEST['id']) ?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Cedric.  I will when I get home from work later today.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @Cedric execution is not getting to the var_dump($admin) line.  It's returning "Database query failed yo." My custom fail message inside confirm_query in 'database.php'

Comment: Side note: You may want to add `$result_set->error` to your custom `die` output to let you know exactly why the query statement failed.

Comment: this is a bit outside the scope of the conversation here, but just thought I should mention that it's not the best idea to perform such actions, like deleting items, with GET requests.. but I guess if you're just learning and not publishing production code like that you might be ok for a while, until you understand the basics..

Comment: to be clear: I am talking about security and XSS, not just of a preference to follow the REST principles or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer on this one ;)

You have:

```
<a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php $admin->id; ?>"> ...
<a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php $admin->id; ?>" ...
```

When it should be:

```
<a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php   echo $admin->id; ?>">...
<a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php echo $admin->id; ?>" ...
                                   ^^^^
```

Comment: lol.  Right on @IncredibleHat.  I'll test this later.  Thank you.

Comment: OR <?= $admin->id; ?> if you have short tags enabled in your php ini settings

Comment: @Cedric Right! I keep forgetting about short tags, as the last few servers I've been working on for the last many years has that disabled :/

Comment: the importance of this echo language construct cannot be overlooked. Just amazing stuff. Thanks again @IncredibleHat.